# Remove standard C++ library from exe file

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I'm use Mingw and try remove code of standard library from my exe file - g++ -nostdlib -o main.exe main.cpp -luser32 . Yes, it work, but first function always become to entry point. Okay, all I need is directly set entry symbol - g++ -nostdlib -e WinMain -o main.exe main.cpp -luser32. Now I get "warning: cannot find entry symbol WinMain; defaulting to 00401000". After this, first function again become entry point. Then, I try change nostdlib to nodefaultlibs and get a lot of error messages about "undefined reference to 'some object'".

Question: so, how I can remove standard library code and set program entry point?

PS g++ --version - g++ (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 5.3.0. main.cpp:

```
#include<windows.h>

//this function called instead of WinMain
int OtherFunction()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"OtherFunction","OtherFunction",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}

int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"WinMain","WinMain",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to remove the standard library from your executable?

Comment: Yes bit unusual wanting to remove std library. Not sure but you may need to declare WinMain as extern "C" otherwise if you are compiling as c++ the linker symbol for your WinMain function gets decorated so isn't "WinMain". Or you should use the (compiler-specific) decorated name in your linker command. If you don't know what this all means use a well-known search engine looking for _C++ name decoration_. Or refer to e.g. http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extern-c-in-c/ but TBH I'm not sure if that is very authoritative. But it might be accurate, not sure. HTH, barny.

Comment: barny: I already try extern "C" and -e WinMain@16. It also don't work. Borgleader: For more small exe files. If I'm use nostdlib, I get 3kb exe file. If I'm don't use nostdlib, I'm get 16 kb. And if I'm use single push_back(1), I get 68kb. I't little annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
extern "C" void WinMain()
{
  // Code here
  ExitProcess(0);
}
```

and link with `-e _WinMain`

Comment: Warning: resolving _WinMain by linking to _WinMain@16... But it work! Thanks.

Comment: @Aso The `@16` is probably because you have the default calling convention set to stdcall? Either way, when you are not using the CRT your WinMain function has zero parameters, not four. Those four parameters are generated by the CRT.